# Susy Responsive Grid & jQuery Masonry

Tags: jquery, html, css, sass, jquery-masonry

I'm having a very annoying problem when trying to implement the jQuery Masonry plugin with a responsive grid system that Susy (SASS grid system) is producing. Below is an image of how it should look:

http://test.tomblanchard.co.uk/Masonry/library/images/HowItShouldLook.gif

I have gone through dozens of articles with a similar problem but can't quite find a solution which benefits my problem. You can see the problem and code here:

http://test.tomblanchard.co.uk/Masonry/

If anyone can help me in the slightest it would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers!
Tom.

Comment: Update: Tweaked some of the plugin settings, it sort of works (it really shouldn't, the settings I have set make no sense) but messes up when the window is re-sized the media quires kick in: http://test.tomblanchard.co.uk/Masonry/UPDATED/

Comment: What did you tweak? Your link doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried alternating the float direction for the ones that need to be on the right (float: right)? I had a similar layout problem earlier, and that seemed to fix the problem for the ones that I needed on the right.

Also, I'm curious about your setup with the responsive+susy. Will you be setting a min-width on each of the divs? I just wonder how masonry works with responsive layouts. Good luck!

Comment: Unfortunately that's not an option, this layout will be used to display posts WordPress product so each post will have to have the same CSS applied.

Comment: So ultimately the page layout will stay like that? What is the use of masonry if there will only be 5 sections? Or is the 1st section a featured and the rest are stacked on each other?